# Gatsby - Layout in wrapPageElement does not update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am having issues with `wrapPageElement` in my Gatsby 4 project.

**wrapPageElement.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

import { PathProvider } from './src/providers/path';
import Layout from './src/components/layout/layout';

// Pass all props (hence the ...props)
// to the layout component so it has access to things like pageContext or location
const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props: { location } }) => (
  <PathProvider path={location.pathname}>
    <Layout>{element}</Layout>
  </PathProvider>
);

export default wrapPageElement;
```

I am using `wrapPageElement` to reuse my Layout across all pages but the Layout does not update its React state properly when included via wrapPageElement. If I render Layout within my pages instead, it works fine.

**gatsby-brower.js**

```js
import './src/styles/global.css';

import CustomProviders from './wrapWithProvider';
import CustomLayout from './wrapPageElement';

export const wrapPageElement = CustomLayout;
export const wrapRootElement = CustomProviders;
```

A view components down in my navbar within Layout I am calling:

```
const { language, defaultLanguage } = useI18next();
console.log('locale', language);
```

When I am changing my page language with I18next, "locale" does not change value. "locale" does however change its value to the updated language if I am rendering the layout within my page.

I should note that I am using TypeScript for all of my project except the Gatsby lifecycle files, e.g. wrapPageElement.js

Any help is appreciated! Not sure where exactly the root cause could be at?

---

Additional code

**Layout component**

```js
 return (
    <div className="page">
      <Helmet>
        <meta httpEquiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0" />
        <meta name="description" content={props.description || description} />
        <meta name="image" content={props.imagePath || image} />
        <title>{props.title || title}</title>
        {props.noIndex && <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />}
      </Helmet>
      <Navbar />
      <main className="m-10 mt-60">{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Navbar component**

```js
  return (
    <nav className="bg-green-300 w-full fixed top-0">
      <ul className="flex flex-row gap-5 m-10">
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="ml-auto">
          <ChangeLanguageLink language="en">EN</ChangeLanguageLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ChangeLanguageLink language="th">TH</ChangeLanguageLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
```

ChangeLanguageLink component

```
const ChangeLanguageLink: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren<ChangeLanguageLinkProps>> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const { originalPath } = useI18next();

  return (
    <LocalizedLink {...props} to={addFinalSlash(originalPath)}>
      {children}
    </LocalizedLink>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I extract is that you are trying to use `I18next` to update the state but you may not need to wrap your whole application to achieve that. The `const { language, defaultLanguage } = useI18next();` will give you the current language.

That said, if you keep wanting your approach, `wrapPageElement` and `wrapRootElement` are wrappers (hence the name) that are shared between Gatsby SSR and Gatsby Browser so in the `gatsby-ssr.js` you need to add the exact information:

```
import CustomProviders from './wrapWithProvider';
import CustomLayout from './wrapPageElement';

export const wrapPageElement = CustomLayout;
export const wrapRootElement = CustomProviders;
```

Keep in mind that `wrapRootElement` is a wrapper that is never unmounted across the application.

Comment: The only reason that I want to wrap the entire application is to reuse the layout across all pages. I added the gatsby-ssr.js (thanks!) but I still have the same issue.

Comment: I am at `/th/about` and click on "EN" I will return to `/` but it should be `/about`. Again it works with the same Layout component, if I use the Layout in each page without `wrapPageElement`. So I am assuming the state updates are defect with `wrapPageElement` and the state of originalPath, language, defaultLanguage from useI18next don't update correctly in wrapPageElement.

Comment: Both (`wrapPageElement` and `wrapRootElement`) components never get unmounted so it makes sense that the language is not getting updated properly :/

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted but maybe for future reference, could you add a small paragraph explaining why never unmounted means stale state? Could be helpful for other people to who stumble across this issue.

Comment: Well, it's what the documentation said. I guess it's because they act as wrappers, not as a context provider so they are not aware of/scope of React state. They get the initial mounted state https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapPageElement (`This is useful for setting wrapper components around pages that won’t get unmounted on page changes`). Try using the `wrapRootElement`